# What should return be for Spring boot @RequestMapping that consumes JSON with produces not defined?

Tags: java, http, spring-boot

I'm seeing an issue and I'm hoping for a sanity check...I'm on the UI end dealing with the return from a Spring Boot controller method. That method returns a String, and its @RequestMapping has 'consumes' defined as JSON. There is no 'produces' defined.

On the UI end, I'm seeing an error because in the response header the Content-Type is listed as application/json, but it's really a string, so when it tries to parse the JSON it fails.

Is Spring assuming a produces type of JSON because the consumes is set to JSON and the produces is not set? Is produces defaulting to whatever consumes is set to, regardless of what the method's return type is?

Here is the method in question, with any identifying details stripped out:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Do the thing", notes = "The API does the thing", response = String.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/do/{the}/thing", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public String doTheThing(
        @ApiParam(value = "HttpHeaders parameter containing user authorization token.")
            @RequestHeader(value = AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NAME) String authorization,
        @ApiParam(value = "Object ID of the existing thing.")
            @PathVariable String thingId,
        @ApiParam(value = "A map of properties for the thing to be created. This typically includes mandatory fields such as thing name and type.")
            @RequestBody Map<String, Object> plan,@RequestParam(value = "tagName", required = false) String tagName) {
    <Code to do the thing, and return a string>
    return response;
}
```

Then, in the UI developer window if I look at the header of the response from that method indicates a Content Type of JSON:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:9000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control- 
Allow-Credentials,Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2018 18:11:22 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Application-Context: bootstrap
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: Including a few lines of code would be helpful to understand problem then reading whole paragraph.

Comment: @want2learn That's fair, I've added a generic version of the method so you can see. All of the annotations etc. are identical to the actual method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem description, what you need is to return json.
If you will return String "I am a test" as a json will be the same. The problem arrives when your application is a spring-mvc application.
In this case it will try to resolve it as a view instead of plain text.

Solutions:

1. Annotate your controller as @RestController
2. Add @ResponseBody to your method

To answer your initial question, spring will try to figure it out which type to return based on your included dependencies. If it is has a dependency to spring-web it will try to resolve a view. 
If you have a @RestController, it will figure it out based on the jackson dependency.

If I did not understand your real problem, please clarify it and add the dependencies as well.

Comment: `@RestController` is a convenience annotation that does nothing more than adding the `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`

Comment: No you understand it...I was in part looking for a sanity check that what I'm seeing is expected. Unfortunately, I am not able to change the current backend controller. I'm wondering if there's a way to get around it on the UI side. I tried adding a responseType of 'text' into the REST request to force it, but in the console it's still appearing as 'application/json' and angular still tries to parse it as JSON.

Comment: @monkeyWithAMachinegun could you try using Postman application and update your question with a response ? To see if the response is actual json or something else.

Comment: The response is definitely JSON as I can see it in the header that comes back...also, when I tried adding an Accept: 'text' into the POST header, I got a 406 Not Acceptable back from the server, so I think it's intending to send only JSON.  Basically they were getting away with this in angular 1.2.x but when I try and go to 1.3.x it is more strict. I think we need to fix this at the root.